# Find the correct package for a given font?

Tags: fonts

Today I did a fresh install of ubuntu 10.04. In my .Xdefaults file there are following lines:

```
urxvt*font:     -adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--24-240-75-75-m-150-iso8859-1
urxvt*boldFont: -adobe-courier-bold-r-normal--24-240-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1
```

Now urxvt only starts if I comment out those lines. I think the reason is that the adobe-courier font seems to be not installed as

```
xlsfonts|grep adobe|grep courier
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-i-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-adobe-standard
```

shows. xfont-base, xfont-100dpi and xfont-75dpi are installed.

Now my question is, how to find out which package contains the desired font.

Comment: You could try to search for the font name in package descriptions or in package contents. You can search for this at http://packages.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a file on your system that belongs to the package whose name you don't know, you can figure out the pkg name with:

```
dpkg -S <file>
```

Most font files are in /usr/share/fonts/.

In there, I (natty) find /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi and other directories.

In 100dpi I find many files, including helvR24.pcf.gz.

So I use dpkg -S on that:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/helvR24.pcf.gz
xfonts-100dpi: /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/helvR24.pcf.gz
$
```

The pkg is listed first: xfonts-100dpi

Answer (score 2):

Packages:

[xfonts-100dpi](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xfonts-100dpi/xfonts-100dpi_1.0.3.tar.gz)

[xfonts-75dpi](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xfonts-75dpi/xfonts-75dpi_1.0.3.tar.gz)

(ISO 10646-1 en ISO 8859-1 fonts in 75 and 100 dots per inch)

Directory `font-adobe-75dpi` holds, amongst others:

[image]